# use function regexp_split_to_table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: stat and conn.
I want to have the expected output .
Does anyone knows how to correct my query below please?

**stat**

```
 id       type        dat_treat
 x1        2          12/03/2020
 x2        2          12/03/2020
 x3        3,4        12/03/2020
```

**conn**

```
  id      date         value      nbr
  x1      12/03/2020   phone    100
  x1      12/03/2020   mail     130
  x2      12/03/2020   phone    300
  x3      12/03/2020.  phone    100
```

**expected output**

```
    x1   2    12/03/2020   230
    x2   2    12/03/2020   300
    x3   3   12/03/2020   100
    x3   4   12/03/2020   100
```

Thank you

```
select date, value as value, id, type as type
from 
(
select conn.id as id, conn.date as date,
regexp_split_to_table(stat.type||',B', ',+') as type,
SUM(conn.value) as value
from conn inner join stat 
on conn.id = stat.id and conn.id = stat.dat_treat 
where conn.date >= '2021-01-01' and conn.date < '2021-02-01'
group by conn.id, conn.date, type
) as c
GROUP BY date, type, id 
        ORDER BY date, type
```

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fecb87bed2cc04fa8dc7214e401f1461)

```
SELECT
    s.id, t, s.dat, c.sum
FROM (
    SELECT                                        -- 1
        id,
        dat,
        SUM(nbr)
    FROM conn
    GROUP BY id, dat
) c
JOIN stat s ON s.id = c.id AND s.dat = c.dat,    -- 2
    regexp_split_to_table(type,',') as t         -- 3
```

1. First aggregate the `nbr` values
2. Join this aggregates on the `stat` table
3. Finally expand the `type`s

Comment: @biwia Did this help? Please don't forget to UPVOTE any helpful answer (that honors the time and effort the repliers invested into your problem). If one answer solves your problem completely, please ACCEPT it additionally to close the question.